# else if statement - contains word remove or add class jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

The last else if contains "Arriving" the string is actually "Arriving date" but I only want to find the first word and then do the logic for adding and removing classes. But I feel I'm not using the .length() correctly for this last one. can you guys help me understand how to test this correctly. the first two conditions work fine.

```
 jQuery("#custcolmen_size, #custcolmen-width").change(function () {

    if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Out of stock")').length){ 
       $(".add2cart-div > input").addClass('disabled').removeClass('cart');
       $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
    } 

    else if($('.stock-message > span:contains("")').length) {
       $(".add2cart-div > input").removeClass('disabled').addClass('cart');
       $(".stock-message > span").removeClass('alert alert-danger');
    }

    else if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Arriving")').length) {
       $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
    }
 });
```

Comment: The middle conditional looks like a good `else` if placed at the end.

Comment: no that's not it it has to do with span:contains("Arriving")').length) I'm only wanting to search for the first word of the string. not sure I'm doing this right.

Comment: Probably need to see some HTML. Possible typo you might've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

actually I wasn't using the if and if else correctly. to resolve this it's if then else if then just if again like this below.

```
          jQuery("#custcolmen_size, #custcolmen-width").change(function () {
                if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Out of stock")').length){ 
                   $(".add2cart-div > input").addClass('disabled').removeClass('cart');
                   $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                  }

          else if($('.stock-message > span:contains("")').length) {
                  $(".add2cart-div > input").removeClass('disabled').addClass('cart');
                  $(".stock-message > span").removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                }

               if($('.stock-message > span:contains("Arriving")').length) {
                  $(".stock-message > span").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                                 }
         });
```

works perfect!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can check if a string contains a particular phrase by using .indexOf(). If the phrase if found the index is returned, if not -1 is returned.

```
var string = "This contains foo";

string.indexOf('foo') > -1  //True
string.indexOf('bar') > -1  //false
```